# MySQL crashes with "buffer overflow detected" when Spring Boot connects

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker-stack

I'm having this hair-pulling issue that has me completely stumped, where spring boot causes mysql to crash. The second my spring-boot app connects to the MySQL, mysqld immediately crashes, with the MySQL logs complaining of a buffer overflow.

This is the spring boot log output:

```
:: JHipster  :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::
2017-05-24 17:54:37.811 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.Application : Starting Application on 79ec0626388d with PID 5 (started by root in /)
2017-05-24 17:54:37.815 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.Application : Running with Spring Boot v1.3.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.4.RELEASE
2017-05-24 17:54:37.815 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.Application : The following profiles are active: aws
2017-05-24 17:54:41.162 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.AsyncConfiguration : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-05-24 17:54:41.479 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.MetricsConfiguration : Registering JVM gauges
2017-05-24 17:54:41.564 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.MetricsConfiguration : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-05-24 17:54:41.817 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.CacheConfiguration : Configuring Hazelcast
2017-05-24 17:54:41.859 INFO 5 --- [ main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.5.4] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2017-05-24 17:54:41.868 INFO 5 --- [ main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.5.4] Picked Address[10.255.0.6]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2017-05-24 17:54:42.086 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Backpressure is disabled
2017-05-24 17:54:42.294 INFO 5 --- [ main] c.h.s.i.o.c.ClassicOperationExecutor : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Starting with 2 generic operation threads and 2 partition operation threads.
2017-05-24 17:54:42.618 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.system : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Hazelcast 3.5.4 (20151125 - 56676b2) starting at Address[10.255.0.6]:5701
2017-05-24 17:54:42.619 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.system : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-05-24 17:54:42.627 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Creating MulticastJoiner
2017-05-24 17:54:42.631 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Address[10.255.0.6]:5701 is STARTING
2017-05-24 17:54:45.355 INFO 5 --- [ main] c.h.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4]
Members [1] {
Member [10.255.0.6]:5701 this
}
2017-05-24 17:54:45.384 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService : [10.255.0.6]:5701 [dev] [3.5.4] Address[10.255.0.6]:5701 is STARTED
2017-05-24 17:54:45.468 DEBUG 5 --- [ cached3] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@2c50466c5 pairs: {GET /version.jsp?version=3.5.4&m=a366cca8-f169-457f-8220-48a80ed9cad2&e=false&l=NULL&p=maven&c=552bbbc9-7e70-4d67-a550-c6f31ad43aa3&crsz=A&cssz=A&hdgb=0&ccpp=0&cdn=0&cjv=0&cuptm=27&nuptm=9368 HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0}{Host: versioncheck.hazelcast.com}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
2017-05-24 17:54:45.470 DEBUG 5 --- [ cached3] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7202deab5 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1}{Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 17:54:45 GMT}
2017-05-24 17:54:45.662 WARN 5 --- [ main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2017-05-24 17:54:45.756 WARN 5 --- [ main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2017-05-24 17:54:46.289 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Web application configuration, using profiles: [aws]
2017-05-24 17:54:46.289 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Registering Clustered Http Session Filter
2017-05-24 17:54:46.294 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-05-24 17:54:46.297 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-05-24 17:54:46.298 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-05-24 17:54:46.301 INFO 5 --- [ main] com.REDACTED.config.WebConfigurer : Web application fully configured
2017-05-24 17:54:46.428 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.CacheConfiguration : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
2017-05-24 17:54:46.434 DEBUG 5 --- [ main] c.REDACTED.config.DatabaseConfiguration : Configuring Datasource
2017-05-24 17:54:46.995 WARN 5 --- [ main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/REDACTED/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization: Communications link failure
```

And the mysql output:

```
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 28560957
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-05-24 17:53:57 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
*** buffer overflow detected ***: mysqld terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ffb11e380e7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xeefa0)[0x7ffb11e36fa0]
mysqld(_Z19find_or_create_hostP10PFS_threadPKcj+0x1d3)[0xac1473]
mysqld(_Z22find_or_create_accountP10PFS_threadPKcjS2_j+0x301)[0xabbc21]
mysqld(_Z18set_thread_accountP10PFS_thread+0x3d)[0xac5afd]
mysqld[0xae6e1d]
mysqld(_Z16acl_authenticateP3THDj+0xba4)[0x6b9814]
mysqld[0x6dd17b]
mysqld(_Z16login_connectionP3THD+0x45)[0x6de055]
mysqld(_Z22thd_prepare_connectionP3THD+0x24)[0x6de5c4]
mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x11c)[0x6de8cc]
mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x6de997]
mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x143)[0xae5183]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50)[0x7ffb132d4b50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffb11e2395d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00f54000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 761 /usr/sbin/mysqld
01154000-01201000 r--p 00b54000 ca:11 761 /usr/sbin/mysqld
01201000-01301000 rw-p 00c01000 ca:11 761 /usr/sbin/mysqld
01301000-01354000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
01a22000-021bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap]
7ffae3bab000-7ffae3bbe000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175287 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7ffae3bbe000-7ffae3dbd000 ---p 00013000 ca:11 1175287 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7ffae3dbd000-7ffae3dbe000 r--p 00012000 ca:11 1175287 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7ffae3dbe000-7ffae3dbf000 rw-p 00013000 ca:11 1175287 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
7ffae3dbf000-7ffae3dc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae3dc1000-7ffae3dc2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae3dc2000-7ffae45c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae45c2000-7ffae45c3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae45c3000-7ffae4dc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae4dc3000-7ffae4dc4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae4dc4000-7ffae55c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae55c4000-7ffae55c5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae55c5000-7ffae5dc5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae5dc5000-7ffae5dc6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae5dc6000-7ffae65c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae65c6000-7ffae65c7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae65c7000-7ffae6dc7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae6dc7000-7ffae6dc8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae6dc8000-7ffae75c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae75c8000-7ffae75c9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae75c9000-7ffae7dc9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae7dc9000-7ffae7dca000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae7dca000-7ffae8858000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae89ec000-7ffae89f1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175266 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
7ffae89f1000-7ffae8bf0000 ---p 00005000 ca:11 1175266 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
7ffae8bf0000-7ffae8bf1000 r--p 00004000 ca:11 1175266 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
7ffae8bf1000-7ffae8bf2000 rw-p 00005000 ca:11 1175266 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
7ffae8bf4000-7ffae8bf5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae8bf5000-7ffae8c35000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae8c35000-7ffae8c36000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae8c36000-7ffae8c76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae8c76000-7ffae8c77000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae8c77000-7ffae9477000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae9477000-7ffae9478000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae9478000-7ffae9c78000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae9c78000-7ffae9c79000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffae9c79000-7ffaea479000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaea479000-7ffaea47a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaea47a000-7ffaeac7a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaeac7a000-7ffaeac7b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaeac7b000-7ffaeb47b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaeb47b000-7ffaeb47c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaeb47c000-7ffaebc7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaebc7c000-7ffaebc7d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaebc7d000-7ffaec47d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaec47d000-7ffaec47e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaec47e000-7ffaecc7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaecc7e000-7ffaecc7f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaecc7f000-7ffaed47f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaed47f000-7ffaed480000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaed480000-7ffaf6afd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaf6afd000-7ffaf6aff000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794746 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6aff000-7ffaf6b04000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794745 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b04000-7ffaf6b09000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794744 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b09000-7ffaf6b0e000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794743 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b0e000-7ffaf6b13000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794742 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b13000-7ffaf6b40000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaf6b40000-7ffaf6b45000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794741 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b45000-7ffaf6b4a000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794740 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b4a000-7ffaf6b4f000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794739 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b4f000-7ffaf6b54000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794738 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b54000-7ffaf6b59000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794737 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b59000-7ffaf6b5e000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794736 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b5e000-7ffaf6b8b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaf6b8b000-7ffaf6b8c000 rw-s 00000000 00:0d 2794734 /[aio] (deleted)
7ffaf6b8c000-7ffaf74b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaf74b3000-7ffaf74be000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175268 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7ffaf74be000-7ffaf76bd000 ---p 0000b000 ca:11 1175268 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7ffaf76bd000-7ffaf76be000 r--p 0000a000 ca:11 1175268 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7ffaf76be000-7ffaf76bf000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:11 1175268 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7ffaf76bf000-7ffaf76c9000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175272 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7ffaf76c9000-7ffaf78c8000 ---p 0000a000 ca:11 1175272 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7ffaf78c8000-7ffaf78c9000 r--p 00009000 ca:11 1175272 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7ffaf78c9000-7ffaf78ca000 rw-p 0000a000 ca:11 1175272 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7ffaf78ca000-7ffaf78df000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175262 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7ffaf78df000-7ffaf7ade000 ---p 00015000 ca:11 1175262 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7ffaf7ade000-7ffaf7adf000 r--p 00014000 ca:11 1175262 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7ffaf7adf000-7ffaf7ae0000 rw-p 00015000 ca:11 1175262 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7ffaf7ae0000-7ffaf7ae2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffaf7ae2000-7ffaf7ae9000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175264 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7ffaf7ae9000-7ffaf7ce8000 ---p 00007000 ca:11 1175264 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7ffaf7ce8000-7ffaf7ce9000 r--p 00006000 ca:11 1175264 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7ffaf7ce9000-7ffaf7cea000 rw-p 00007000 ca:11 1175264 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7ffaf7cea000-7ffb11d48000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb11d48000-7ffb11ec9000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175236 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffb11ec9000-7ffb120c9000 ---p 00181000 ca:11 1175236 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffb120c9000-7ffb120cd000 r--p 00181000 ca:11 1175236 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffb120cd000-7ffb120ce000 rw-p 00185000 ca:11 1175236 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffb120ce000-7ffb120d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb120d3000-7ffb120e8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175250 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffb120e8000-7ffb122e8000 ---p 00015000 ca:11 1175250 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffb122e8000-7ffb122e9000 rw-p 00015000 ca:11 1175250 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffb122e9000-7ffb1236a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175255 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7ffb1236a000-7ffb12569000 ---p 00081000 ca:11 1175255 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7ffb12569000-7ffb1256a000 r--p 00080000 ca:11 1175255 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7ffb1256a000-7ffb1256b000 rw-p 00081000 ca:11 1175255 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7ffb1256b000-7ffb12653000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1176097 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7ffb12653000-7ffb12853000 ---p 000e8000 ca:11 1176097 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7ffb12853000-7ffb1285b000 r--p 000e8000 ca:11 1176097 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7ffb1285b000-7ffb1285d000 rw-p 000f0000 ca:11 1176097 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7ffb1285d000-7ffb12872000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb12872000-7ffb12874000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175244 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7ffb12874000-7ffb12a74000 ---p 00002000 ca:11 1175244 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7ffb12a74000-7ffb12a75000 r--p 00002000 ca:11 1175244 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7ffb12a75000-7ffb12a76000 rw-p 00003000 ca:11 1175244 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7ffb12a76000-7ffb12a7e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175242 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
7ffb12a7e000-7ffb12c7d000 ---p 00008000 ca:11 1175242 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
7ffb12c7d000-7ffb12c7e000 r--p 00007000 ca:11 1175242 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
7ffb12c7e000-7ffb12c7f000 rw-p 00008000 ca:11 1175242 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
7ffb12c7f000-7ffb12cad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb12cad000-7ffb12cb4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175289 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7ffb12cb4000-7ffb12eb3000 ---p 00007000 ca:11 1175289 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7ffb12eb3000-7ffb12eb4000 r--p 00006000 ca:11 1175289 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7ffb12eb4000-7ffb12eb5000 rw-p 00007000 ca:11 1175289 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7ffb12eb5000-7ffb12ecb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175308 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7ffb12ecb000-7ffb130ca000 ---p 00016000 ca:11 1175308 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7ffb130ca000-7ffb130cb000 r--p 00015000 ca:11 1175308 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7ffb130cb000-7ffb130cc000 rw-p 00016000 ca:11 1175308 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7ffb130cc000-7ffb130cd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 674 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
7ffb130cd000-7ffb132cc000 ---p 00001000 ca:11 674 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
7ffb132cc000-7ffb132cd000 r--p 00000000 ca:11 674 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
7ffb132cd000-7ffb132ce000 rw-p 00001000 ca:11 674 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
7ffb132ce000-7ffb132e5000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175283 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7ffb132e5000-7ffb134e4000 ---p 00017000 ca:11 1175283 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7ffb134e4000-7ffb134e5000 r--p 00016000 ca:11 1175283 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7ffb134e5000-7ffb134e6000 rw-p 00017000 ca:11 1175283 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7ffb134e6000-7ffb134ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb134ea000-7ffb1350a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:11 1175220 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffb1350a000-7ffb13706000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb13706000-7ffb13709000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffb13709000-7ffb1370a000 r--p 0001f000 ca:11 1175220 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffb1370a000-7ffb1370b000 rw-p 00020000 ca:11 1175220 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffb1370b000-7ffb1370c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffdf7c05000-7ffdf7c26000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
7ffdf7d83000-7ffdf7d85000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 [vvar]
7ffdf7d85000-7ffdf7d87000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vsyscall]
17:54:46 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68245 K bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Thread pointer: 0x1f8ac70
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7ffae8c33e40 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x8bda5e]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x471)[0x6984e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0a0)[0x7ffb132dd0a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7ffb11d7a165]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180)[0x7ffb11d7d3e0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6c39b)[0x7ffb11db439b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ffb11e380e7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xeefa0)[0x7ffb11e36fa0]
mysqld(_Z19find_or_create_hostP10PFS_threadPKcj+0x1d3)[0xac1473]
mysqld(_Z22find_or_create_accountP10PFS_threadPKcjS2_j+0x301)[0xabbc21]
mysqld(_Z18set_thread_accountP10PFS_thread+0x3d)[0xac5afd]
mysqld[0xae6e1d]
mysqld(_Z16acl_authenticateP3THDj+0xba4)[0x6b9814]
mysqld[0x6dd17b]
mysqld(_Z16login_connectionP3THD+0x45)[0x6de055]
mysqld(_Z22thd_prepare_connectionP3THD+0x24)[0x6de5c4]
mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x11c)[0x6de8cc]
mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x6de997]
mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x143)[0xae5183]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50)[0x7ffb132d4b50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffb11e2395d]
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

The MySQL "buffer overflow detected" line occurs at exactly 17:54:46 (I checked), the exact same time that the exception is thrown in the Spring boot logs, so one is causing the other.

Here's the spring config file:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: aws
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://REDACTED:3306/REDACTED?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
        # add &rewriteBatchedStatements=true to enable rewriting statements into batches - but requires further jpa properties below (MySQL specific)
        # add &profileSQL=true to profile sql statements
        name:
        username: REDACTED
        password: REDACTED
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
        database: MYSQL
        show_sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.REDACTED.config.hazelcast.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
            hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
            # Enable the following for batch rewriting
            # hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 50
            # hibernate.order_inserts: true
            # hibernate.order_updates: true
    mail:
        host: REDACTED
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false

liquibase:
    contexts: dev

server:
    port: 8080
    session:
        timeout: 28800 # 8 hours

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
    datasource: # JHipster-specific configuration, in addition to the standard spring.datasource properties
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
    cache: # Hibernate 2nd level cache, used by CacheConfiguration
        timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
        hazelcast:
            backupCount: 1
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: REDACTED@localhost
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
        spark:
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 9999
        graphite:
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 2003
            prefix: REDACTED
    tableHistory:
        queryLog: /queryLog.txt
        bookUpdate: /update_book.php
        bookTag: /update_book_modifications.php
    security:
        authentication:
            oauth:
                # Token is valid 8 hours
                tokenValidityInSeconds: 28800


bridgeresource:
    communityCredentials:
        url: https://REDACTED/REDACTED/rest/v1/
        username: REDACTED
        password: REDACTED
    version: 30

ga:
    path: /assets/bundles/REDACTED/js/ga/ga.dev.js
```

EDIT: Some more info.. I'm running these services in Docker containers. This error happens when I try to run them as a Docker Stack.. but here's what's strange--when I run them 'manually' (ie. through simple "docker run" commands) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check below mentioned points:

A buffer overflow occurs when:
1.You use mysql:5.7.16 or mysql:5.7.17
2.You map a nonexistent/empty folder to /etc/mysql/conf.d
3. Your docker-compose project has a long name

And you connect to mysql.

Source: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/243

Comment: I'm using mysql:5.6.23, I'm not doing anything with /etc/mysql/conf.d (in my docker compose the only thing I'm mounting is /var/lib/mysql), and the project name is only 11 characters.

The error also only happens with docker-compose. When I start each service manually it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is a very long container name. It is composed from a project directory name and the service name in docker-compose.yml file.

The solution would be to make one or both of them shorter. The example:

> «Access denied for user 'mysql'@'somelongnamethatwillbreakmysql_web_run_2.somelongnamethatwillbre'.

Source: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/243#issuecomment-277965384